# Analytic continuation of zeta is meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ with simple pole at 1

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

We have the following identity:
For some contour $\gamma$ and $\forall s \in \mathbb{C} $  Re $s > 1$:
$$-2i\sin(\pi s) \Gamma(s)\zeta(s)= \Large\int_{\gamma} \frac{(-z)^{s-1}}{e^z-1}dz$$

The question was:
Plug in the formula $\sin(\pi s) \Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)=\pi$ into the identity to conclude that $\zeta$ extends to a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$ whose only possible pole is a simple pole at $s=1$.

The first part was easy:
$-2i\sin(\pi s) \Gamma(s)\zeta(s)= -2i\sin(\pi s) \Gamma(s)\frac{\Gamma(1-s)}{\Gamma(1-s)}\zeta(s) = \frac {-2\pi i}{\Gamma(1-s)}\zeta(s) = \Large\int_{\gamma} \frac{(-z)^{s-1}}{e^z-1}dz$
$$\Rightarrow \zeta(s) = -\frac {\Gamma(1-s)}{2\pi i}\Large\int_{\gamma} \frac{(-z)^{s-1}}{e^z-1}dz$$

My question is how do you show that $-\frac {\Gamma(1-s)}{2\pi i}\Large{\int_{\gamma} \frac{(-z)^{s-1}}{e^z-1}}dz$ is meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ with a simple pole at $s=1$ ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You start by showing that

$$I(s) = \int_\gamma \frac{(-z)^{s-1}}{e^z - 1}\, dz$$

is an entire function. The estimate

$$\left\lvert \frac{(-z)^{\sigma + it-1}}{e^z-1}\right\rvert \leqslant e^{\pi\lvert t\rvert} \frac{\lvert z\rvert^{\sigma-1}}{\lvert e^z-1\rvert}$$

shows that the integral exists for all $s = \sigma +it \in\mathbb{C}$, and showing its holomorphicity can be done in various ways (Morera's theorem for example).

Since $\Gamma$ is an entire meromorphic function, it follows that

$$-\frac{\Gamma(1-s)}{2\pi i}\cdot I(s)$$

is also an entire meromorphic function. Since $I(1) = 2\pi i \neq 0$, it has a simple pole in $1$ arising from the pole of $\Gamma$ in $0$. Since $I(k) = 0$ for $k \geqslant 2$, as $\dfrac{(-z)^{k-1}}{e^z-1}$ has a removable singularity in $z = 0$ then, that is the only pole.

For an integer $k \geqslant 2$, let $m = k-1$. Then $(-z)^m$ is an entire function vanishing in $0$. The denominator $e^z-1$ has a simple zero in $z=0$, and that is cancelled by the zero of the numerator, hence

$$\frac{(-z)^m}{e^z-1} = (-1)^m \frac{z^m}{z + \frac{z^2}{2} + \frac{z^3}{3!} + \dotsc} = (-1)^m \frac{z^{m-1}}{1 + \frac{z}{2} + \frac{z^2}{3!} + \dotsc}$$

has a removable singularity in $z = 0$. The integrand is thus holomorphic in the strip $-2\pi i < \operatorname{Im} z < 2\pi i$, and by Cauchy's integral theorem,

$$\int_{\gamma_R} \frac{(-z)^m}{e^z-1}\,dz = 0,$$

where $\gamma_R$ is the closed contour obtained by cutting off the part $\operatorname{Re} z > R$ from $\gamma$ and closing it with a vertical segment on $\operatorname{Re} Z = R$. Since the integrand decays exponentially for $\operatorname{Re} z \to +\infty$,

$$I(m+1) = \int_\gamma \frac{(-z)^m}{e^z-1}\,dz = \lim_{R\to+\infty} \int_{\gamma_R} \frac{(-z)^m}{e^z-1}\,dz = 0$$

for $m \geqslant 1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Everything is perfectly clear now beside from your last sentence. Can you just clarify it ?

Comment: Can you be more explicit what needs to be clarified? That $I(k) = 0$ for $k \geqslant 2$ ($k$ always an integer, of course), or that that implies that $s = 1$ is the only pole of $\zeta$? (or both?)

Comment: I mean that $I(k) = 0 $ for $k\geqslant 2$ and that $\frac{(-z)^{k-1}}{e^z-1}$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$ isn't so clear to me

Comment: I've added an explanation of that. If that doesn't suffice, yell.

Comment: Now it's perfect