# Proof of Analytic Continuation of Zeta Function

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that zeta function is continuable in the complex plane with only singularity a simple pole at s = 1.

Required to use the formula $ζ(s) = \frac{1}{Γ(s)} \int_0^1\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx+\frac{1}{Γ(s)} \int_1^\infty\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx$.

I used some methods from functional analysis, but I imagine that there is a short solution.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639256/analytic-continuation-of-zeta-is-meromorphic-on-mathbbc-with-simple-pole-at?rq=1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expand $\frac{x}{e^x-1}$ in power series in the $\int_0^1$ integral and use the theorem that $\Gamma(s)$ has no zero and simple poles at negative integers (which follows for example from that $\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)-\pi/\sin(\pi s)$ is entire and bounded)